# Spring init-method and destroy-method

Tags: java, spring

Is spting IOC init-method and destroy-met written while defining the bean same as the java `<init>` and finalize() methods respectively ? 
If so, then like finalize() method is called by the garbage collector, is the method specified in the property destroy-method too called by GC ?
When is the method in destroy-method property called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't wait for the GC but rather for an explicit decision to stop the spring context. For example if a programmer explicitly invokes FactoryBean.destroySingletons(), or implicitly by calling registerShutdownHook() which means destruction would occur on system' exit.

If you didn't see your shutdonw method called, it's probably because you just allowed the 'main' thread to finish without explicitly destroying the context. If it's (say) ClasspathXmlApplicationContext , try the aforementioned registerShutdownHook

BTW Note it only works for singleton scoped beans (which is the default, and most commonly used, type)

Answer (score 1):

They are not linked with the garbage collector or any JVM life cycle but to your container. For instance init-method will be called after instanciation and properties set. The other one, destroy-method will be called when you context is closing.